# TypeError: validateOptions is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm coding using React.js and TypeScript and though these code changes worked before when I committed -- something happened at some point and this error persists across all the different commits.

I'm not sure where this bug is as Visual Studio Code isn't picking anything up in index.tsx

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.tsx
TypeError: validateOptions is not a function
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Hey，have you found any solutions?

Comment: Wondering the same.. I am suddenly seeing this issue out of nowhere.

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution ?